# WPF Memory leak on window closing

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-3.5

I have "MainWindow", in which i create new windows, named "Maket", after closing they are not released from memory. So i post a picture of tree, from ANTS memory profiler, if code needed i can post it.
What is the problem, why they are not released?

[image]

TreeAndGrids.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="ССПИ.Интерфейс.TreeAndGrids"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:DataBase="clr-namespace:ССПИ.DataBase"
         xmlns:OpenSourceControls1="clr-namespace:OpenSourceControls;assembly=DockPanelSplitter"
         xmlns:Helpers="clr-namespace:ССПИ.Helpers"
         xmlns:Интерфейс="clr-namespace:ССПИ.Интерфейс"
         xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit"
         xmlns:Primitives="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=WPFToolkit"
         xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
         xmlns:chrome="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Chromes;assembly=WPFToolkit.Extended"
         xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Core.Converters;assembly=WPFToolkit.Extended" mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="379" d:DesignWidth="600" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded_1">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="SeparatorStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,0,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFC5C5C5"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0,10,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    </Style>


    <conv:InverseBoolConverter x:Key="InverseBoolConverter" />

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PopupDarkBorderBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0" />
        <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375" />
        <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375" />
        <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PopupBackgroundBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#FFffffff" />
                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FFE8EBED" />
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <Style x:Key="DropDownButtonStyle"
         TargetType="{x:Type xctk:DropDownButton}">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource NuclearButtonFocusVisual}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource OutsideFontColor}" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type xctk:DropDownButton}">
                    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="PART_DropDownButton"
                            Grid.Column="1" 
                            IsChecked="{Binding IsOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            IsHitTestVisible="{Binding IsOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolConverter}}">

                            <ToggleButton.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </ToggleButton.Template>
                            <Grid>
                                <chrome:ButtonChrome VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" x:Name="ToggleButtonChrome"
                                         CornerRadius="2.75"
                                         RenderChecked="{TemplateBinding IsOpen}"
                                         RenderEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsEnabled}"
                                                    RenderMouseOver="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=PART_DropDownButton}"
                                                    RenderPressed="{Binding IsPressed, ElementName=PART_DropDownButton}">
                                    <chrome:ButtonChrome.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type chrome:ButtonChrome}" BasedOn="{x:Null}">
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFontColor}"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
                                            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{DynamicResource NuclearButtonFocusVisual}"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonChromeTemplate}" />
                                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                        </Style>
                                    </chrome:ButtonChrome.Style>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="true" />
                                        <Grid x:Name="arrowGlyph" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="4,3,4,3" Grid.Column="1">
                                            <Path Width="7" Height="4" Data="M 0,1 C0,1 0,0 0,0 0,0 3,0 3,0 3,0 3,1 3,1 3,1 4,1 4,1 4,1 4,0 4,0 4,0 7,0 7,0 7,0 7,1 7,1 7,1 6,1 6,1 6,1 6,2 6,2 6,2 5,2 5,2 5,2 5,3 5,3 5,3 4,3 4,3 4,3 4,4 4,4 4,4 3,4 3,4 3,4 3,3 3,3 3,3 2,3 2,3 2,3 2,2 2,2 2,2 1,2 1,2 1,2 1,1 1,1 1,1 0,1 0,1 z" Fill="#FF000000" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </chrome:ButtonChrome>
                            </Grid>
                        </ToggleButton>

                        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" 
                     AllowsTransparency="True"
                     StaysOpen="False"
                     Focusable="False"
                     IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=PART_DropDownButton}">
                            <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="{StaticResource PopupBackgroundBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PopupDarkBorderBrush}">
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding DropDownContent}" />
                            </Border>
                        </Popup>

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>



    <Style x:Key="myHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="buttonsstyle" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="36" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="90" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type chrome:ButtonChrome}" BasedOn="{x:Null}" x:Key="toggle">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFontColor}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{DynamicResource NuclearButtonFocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonChromeTemplate}" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>

    <Helpers:ClientsConnectionsConverter x:Key="Converter"/>
    <Helpers:TreeConverter x:Key="treeConverter"/>
    <Helpers:ZeroToHiddenConverter x:Key="zeroToHiddenConverter"/>
    <Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Controls:DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<DockPanel>
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <DockPanel Height="Auto" Name="dockPanel2" LastChildFill="False"  Margin="0,0, 0,7">
            <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Left" Name="grid1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Button Margin="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  Name="button1" Click="button1_Click"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="36" Width="36" ToolTip="Предыдущие сутки">
                    <Button.Content>
                        <Image Source="/АСВПИ;component/images/previous.png" Stretch="None" />
                    </Button.Content>
                </Button>
                <Controls:DatePicker Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,0,0,0" CalendarOpened="datePicker1_CalendarOpened" FontSize="22" FontFamily="Tahoma"  Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="datePicker1" SelectedDateChanged="datePicker1_SelectedDateChanged" Width="150" ToolTip="Операционные сутки" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Normal" />
                <Button Margin="1" Name="button2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Click="button2_Click"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="36" Width="36" ToolTip="Следующие сутки">
                    <Button.Content>
                        <Image Source="/АСВПИ;component/images/next.png" Stretch="None" />
                    </Button.Content>
                </Button>
                <Border Grid.Column="3" Name="sep1" Style="{StaticResource SeparatorStyle}"/>
                <ComboBox Grid.Column="4" FontSize="22" Name="pl_lev_combo" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Height="36" Width="160" HorizontalAlignment="Right" ToolTip="Уровень планирования" Margin="0,6,0,6">
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="ОУ" IsSelected="True"></ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="X-1"></ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="X-2"></ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="ВСВГО"></ComboBoxItem>
                </ComboBox>
                <Grid Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition  Name="seccolumn"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Name="compare_label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0"  Margin="10,12,83,12" Height="24" Visibility="Collapsed" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Tahoma" Width="89" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">Сравнить с</Label>
                <ComboBox Grid.Column="1"  Name="secondary_pl_lev" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Height="17" FontSize="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="68" Margin="0,0,20,8">
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="" IsSelected="True"></ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="ОУ"></ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="X-1"></ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="X-2"></ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="ВСВГО"></ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Об.х. ОУ"></ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Об.х. Х-1"></ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Об.х. Х-2"></ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Об.х. ВСВГО"></ComboBoxItem>
                </ComboBox>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Border Name="sep2" Style="{StaticResource SeparatorStyle}"/>
            <chrome:ButtonChrome  Style="{StaticResource toggle}"  Height="48" Width="48" Name="button4" PreviewMouseDown="button4_Click">
                <chrome:ButtonChrome.Content>
                    <Image Source="/АСВПИ;component/images/check.png" Stretch="None"  />
                </chrome:ButtonChrome.Content>
            </chrome:ButtonChrome>


            <xctk:DropDownButton Height="48" Width="120" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource DropDownButtonStyle}"  Name="ou_send" Content="ОУ">
                <xctk:DropDownButton.DropDownContent>


                    <ListBox Name="ou_send_menu" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <MenuItem Header="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=Converter}, ConverterParameter=OUButtons}" ToolTip="{Binding Address}" Click="OUSendClick"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>

                </xctk:DropDownButton.DropDownContent>
            </xctk:DropDownButton>

            <xctk:DropDownButton Name="rsv_vsvgo_send" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource DropDownButtonStyle}" Width="120" Height="48" Content="РСВ/ВСВГО">
                <xctk:DropDownButton.DropDownContent>
                    <ListBox Name="rsv_vsvgo_menu">
                        <ListBox.Items>
                            <MenuItem Header="Отправить Х-1" Name="x1send" Click="x1send_Click">
                            </MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem Header="Отправить Х-2" Name="x2send" Click="x2send_Click">
                            </MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem Header="Отправить ВСВГО" Name="vsvgosend" Click="vsvgosend_Click">
                            </MenuItem>
                        </ListBox.Items>
                    </ListBox>
                </xctk:DropDownButton.DropDownContent>
            </xctk:DropDownButton>
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Left" Name="Dock_Separate" MinWidth="150" MaxWidth="900" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Name="tree_h" Height="1*" MinHeight="200" ></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition MinHeight="150" Height="150"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Slider
x:Name="treeScaleSlider" Visibility="Collapsed"
ToolTip="Determines the UI scale factor."
Value="1" Minimum="0.1" Maximum="4"/>
        <TreeView Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="LightGray" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="treeObjects" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SelectedItemChanged="treeObjects_SelectedItemChanged" KeyDown="treeObjects_KeyDown" PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
            <TreeView.LayoutTransform>

                    <ScaleTransform 
        CenterX="0" CenterY="0"
        ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=treeScaleSlider,Path=Value}"
        ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=treeScaleSlider,Path=Value}"
    />

            </TreeView.LayoutTransform>
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightGray"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="LightGray"/>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DataBase:Objects}" ItemsSource="{Binding SubObjects}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="{Binding IconSource}"/>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding ColorInTree}"><TextBlock.Text><MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource treeConverter}" ConverterParameter="NameAndId"><Binding Path="name" /><Binding Path="id" /></MultiBinding></TextBlock.Text></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">

                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                                   Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive"
                                   Value="false"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter
                            Property="Background"
                            Value="LightGray"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                            Value="Black"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>

                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding ColorInTree}"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <TreeView.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding}" Visibility="{Binding Path=ContextMenuItems.Count,Converter={StaticResource zeroToHiddenConverter}}">
                </ContextMenu>
            </TreeView.ContextMenu>
        </TreeView>
        <GridSplitter ResizeDirection="Rows" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Width="Auto"  Height="3"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,5" Visibility="Collapsed" Name="zvk_panel">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Image Grid.Column="0" Name="zvkImageStatus" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="/АСВПИ;component/images/waiting.png" ToolTip="Подключение к серверу 'Заявки'..."  Height="20" Width="20"></Image>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Name="zvk_label" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Text="Заявки" FontSize="14"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="zvk_result" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Visibility="Collapsed"  Text="Заявок нет"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>

            <Controls:DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Name="zvk_datagrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="LightGray" Background="White" CanUserReorderColumns="False" GridLinesVisibility="Vertical" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalGridLinesBrush="LightGray" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" PreviewMouseDown="zvk_datagrid_PreviewMouseDown">
                <Controls:DataGrid.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightGray"/>
                </Controls:DataGrid.Resources>
                <Controls:DataGrid.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="Controls:DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                    </Style>
                </Controls:DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                    <Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Станция" Width="Auto" MinWidth="100" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}" SortMemberPath="station" CanUserSort="True">
                        <Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="Primitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                            </Style>
                        </Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding station}"></TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>


                    <Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ΔP" Width="Auto" MinWidth="30" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}" SortMemberPath="zvk.power_down" CanUserSort="True">
                        <Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="Primitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                            </Style>
                        </Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding zvk.power_down}"></TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Дата" Width="Auto" MinWidth="90" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}" SortMemberPath="zvk.date_begin" CanUserSort="True">
                        <Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="Primitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                            </Style>
                        </Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding zvk.date_begin, StringFormat={}{0:dd.MM.yyyy H:mm}}"></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding zvk.date_end, StringFormat={}{0:dd.MM.yyyy H:mm}}"></TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </Controls:DataGrid.Columns>
            </Controls:DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <OpenSourceControls1:DockPanelSplitter x:Name="separator1" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></OpenSourceControls1:DockPanelSplitter>
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" MinWidth="300">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" MinHeight="200"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition MinHeight="150" Height="150"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Row="0" Name="border"  BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="0.5" Background="White" MinWidth="400">
            <Интерфейс:Grid x:Name="grid" MinWidth="300"></Интерфейс:Grid>
        </Border>
        <GridSplitter ResizeDirection="Rows" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Width="Auto"  Height="3"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition MinHeight="30" MaxHeight="30"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14">Паспортные данные</Label>
            <Controls:DataGrid BorderBrush="LightGray"  Grid.Row="1" MinHeight="100" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableColumnVirtualization="true" EnableRowVirtualization="true" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="false" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" Name="dataGridConst"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="White" VerticalGridLinesBrush="LightGray" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="LightGray">
                    <Controls:DataGrid.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="White"/>
                </Controls:DataGrid.Resources>
                <Controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                    <Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Наименование" Width="*">
                        <Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="Primitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                            </Style>
                        </Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding name}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Значение" Width="*">
                        <Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="Primitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                            </Style>
                        </Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding value}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </Controls:DataGrid.Columns>

            </Controls:DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: i posted xaml, its my control, it contains combobox, named "secondary_pl_lev"

Comment: Try to analyse the graph and eliminate corrupt area. As per the root, leak is somewhere in comboboxItem's. Try removing that and see if memory leak still persists and post your findings here since analysing without code won't be possible.

Comment: so i removed all comboboxitems, and problem disaperead. what it can be&

Comment: Try detaching all events on your control on windows close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For WPF application, there are numerous causes on memory leak. Can be that the event handler hasn't been removed on closing, binding to a non dependedency property, and can be anything else.

Visit this website for sample cases and see which one fits for your case, because you didn't post the whole code, including the code behind for your application.

http://svetoslavsavov.blogspot.com/2010/05/memory-leaks-in-wpf-applications.html